# Ideal Generated by the Union of Two Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals of a ring $R$. Prove that $I+J$ is an ideal of $R$ and that $I+J=\langle I\cup J\rangle$, the ideal of $R$ generated by $I\cup J$.

Comment: I know how to prove the first part. The second part is my problem. Please help.

Comment: What do elements of $I + J$ look like? What does $\langle \rangle$ mean?

Comment: Hint: since $0 \in I$ and $0 \in J$, the containment $\langle I \cup J \rangle \subseteq I + J$ is obvious. Can you prove the $\langle I \cup J \rangle \supseteq I + J$?

Comment: I've learned that $I+J=\{i+j|i\in I\text{ and }j\in J\}$

Comment: What is the definition of an ideal? In particular, note that $I \subset I\cup J$ and $J \subset I \cup J$. By the definition of an ideal, what must be true?

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, is $\langle I\cup J\rangle$ a collection of finite sums of products from $I$ and $J$?

Comment: $\langle I \cup J \rangle$ is the ideal generated by elements of $I \cup J$. Since it is an ideal, by definition, it therefore contains any sum $r_{1}i + r_{2}j$ for $i,j \in I\cup J$ and $r_{1}, r_{2} \in R$. What can you say, then?

Comment: I think I got ur point. Since I and J are ideals, $r_1i+r_2j$ simply becomes $i+j$. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AlexWertheim $<I \cup J>$ is an ideal only when I $\subset$ J or J $\subset$ I, right?

Answer (score 4):

Hint.

You want to prove that that $I + J$ is the smallest ideal containing $I \cup J$. This means you need to prove two points.

1. $I + J$ contains $I \cup J$.
2. If $K$ is any other ideal containing $I \cup J$, then $I + J \subseteq K$.